# Is this a good definition of schema migration?

Tags: schema-migration

I'm trying to preserve the meaning of the English word 'migration' in the definition, and I think I might be able to do that without making up a fake definition. Here goes:

> A schema migration is the change of a database's schema from one **state** to another through time, as is distinct from the more general definition of data migration, in which data is moved from one **location** to another.

Anyway, this is basically original research, because it's hard to find these kinds of definitions sometimes. So I'd really appreciate some expert feedback.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do ?

Comment: FWIW, schema migrations are just a management pattern for schema revisions. Data migration is unrelated in concept and just happens to share the same word "*migration*", with a different meaning. It's almost akin to the word "*trunk*" can mean two unrelated things, a body part of an elephant vs a body part of a tree.

Comment: @Rohit Gupta My apologies for not adding more context. I am trying to write a Ruby on Rails guide. In it, there is a section on migrations, which in the context of Rails, means schema migrations. I am trying to include a definition that is as approachable and understandable as possible. I'm not happy with e.g. the Wikipedia definition. I think the first thing a person would wonder is, "what is it exactly that's being migrated?" So, I'm trying to answer that directly.

Comment: @J.D. To be fair, it's the Wikipedia article on 'data migration' that includes schema migrations as a subsection. But, idk.

Comment: @J.D. also a very large suitcase/box for storing/transporting luggage, **and**  (didn't know this before), [the main part of a blood vessel or nerve](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trunk)! Also, American word for the boot of a car and one can wear swimming trunks (v. old-fashioned). :-)

Comment: @Vérace Naming things are hard. 